# Mockito test DAO with mocked objects

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, dao

I would like to test this DAO method

```
//in GrabDao.java
public WrapperProject getChildren(Integer entityId, String entityType){

    EntityDao entityDao = new EntityDao();
    UserDao userDao = new UserDao();

    EntityBase entity = entityDao.getEntityById(entityId, entityType);
    Date dateProjet = userDao.getOrganismeFromSession().getExercice().getDateProjet();

    return new Wrapper(dateProjet, entity);
}
```

This is what I've tried so far

```
    //in GrabDaoTest.java
    Integer paramEntityId = 1; 
    String paramEntityType = "type";

    EntityBase entityBase = Mockito.mock(EntityBase.class);

    EntityDao entityDao = Mockito.mock(EntityDao.class);
    when(entityDao.getEntityById(paramEntityId, paramEntityType)).thenReturn(entityBase);

    UserDao userDao = Mockito.mock(UserDao.class);
    Organisme organisme = Mockito.mock(Organisme.class);
    Exercice excercice = Mockito.mock(Exercice.class);

    when(userDao.getOrganismeFromSession()).thenReturn(organisme);
    when(organisme.getExercice()).thenReturn(excercice);
    when(userDao.getOrganismeFromSession().getExercice().getDateProjet()).thenReturn(new GregorianCalendar(2000, 01, 01).getTime());
```

Now I would like to test that the **getChildren** with fake params **paramEntityId** and **paramEntityType** will correctly return a WrapperProject 1 and 01/01/2000 **using the mocked methods** but I can't figured out how to launch the read method telling her to use the mocked dao

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is not test friendly, especially this two lines are very bad for testing:

```
EntityDao entityDao = new EntityDao();
UserDao userDao = new UserDao();
```

This code should be moved from this method to Factory or injected with containter like Spring (Dependency Injection).

Mockito alone can't test code like this. Your method should do one thing only, creating Daos is other job.

I will recommend you two films from [GoogleTechTalks](https://www.youtube.com/user/GoogleTechTalks?feature=watch):

- [How to Write Clean, Testable Code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XcT4yYu_TTs&list=PLpJsMsDqbY0zZRd9FUQJxuE0jV4-xUsId)
- [The Clean Code Talks - Don't Look For Things!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0&list=PLpJsMsDqbY0zZRd9FUQJxuE0jV4-xUsId)

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I will watch them and post my final working answer here

Comment: I fully agree with MariuszS here.  In [my article on the Mockito wiki](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/MockingObjectCreation), I mention a couple of ways you can use Mockito to help test code that creates new objects.  Have a quick look and see if either of them are likely to be useful here.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more correct to say that Mockito simply doesn't support mocking of `new`-ed objects? Because if it did (which is perfectly possible), the `getChildren` method would be easily testable as is. And DI is not a way to replace use of `new`; it's a way to "separate configuration from use", which doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: @Rogério *DI makes unit testing much easier.* http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/140992/is-dependency-injection-essential-for-unit-testing

Comment: @MariuszS Well, most answers to that question say "no". The reality, of course, is that the ease of unit testing has nothing to do with DI or no DI, but everything to do with the ability to *isolate* the unit under test from its external dependencies. PowerMockito, for example, is a mocking/isolation tool which does the job just fine with or without DI. Often, when people talk about these supposed testability issues, they don't seem to be aware that proper solutions already exist.

Comment: @Rogério Ok, what I would to say, is that code written with DI in mind is easy to test without tools like PowerMockito :) DI helps writes testable code. Also David second pattern is about *injecting* :)

Comment: @MariuszS I agree, DI can help to write testable code. The same can be said of good testing tools (mocking included). On the other hand, DI-oriented code also tends to be procedural in style, rather than object-oriented; it's very common to see stateless service/DAO "objects" which are injected and injected into, combined with value "objects" (neither of which are truly objects, obviously). So, DI also "helps" write poor code (of which I have seen a lot already in projects using Spring, CDI, or .NET). Another point is that mocking tools with arbitrary limitations also hinder good OO code.